# Is there a way to block paths in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am pretty new to angular and web programming in general and I am trying to create a wizard-like form, including 5 steps. I set up a routing for the 5 steps and my goal is to prevent the user jumping to another step via the url. He should only use the two "next" and "back" buttons provided by me and the navigation should be done only via these buttons. I know there are also ways to do this without the routing, but I figured it was a good practice to work with routes.

These are my routes:

```js
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '1', component: FormContainer1Component },
    { path: '2', component: FormContainer2Component },
    { path: '3', component: FormContainer3Component },
    { path: '4', component: FormContainer4Component },
    { path: '5', component: FormContainer5Component }
];
```

Comment: We can use [RouteGuards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) provided by angular.

Comment: Why would you even create different routes for each form step?

Answer (score 5):

To prevent a user for accessing a component through routing you can use **guards**. Guards are as services that return a true a false value base a condition, if the condition is succeeds, the user can access the component.

This is the guard in the router :

```
{
  path: 'cart',
  component : CartComponent,
  canActivate : [AuthGuard, NoAdminGuard]
}
```

This is the guard itself :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../service/auth.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor( private _authService : AuthService,
      private _router : Router){}

  canActivate () : boolean{
    if(this._authService.loggedIn()){
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
      return true
    } else{
      this._router.navigate(['/login'])
      return false
    }
  }  
}
```

You can create a guard with:

```
ng generate guard <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UrlHandlingStrategy

in your app.module you can import

```
import { UrlHandlingStrategy, UrlTree} from '@angular/router';
```

and

```
     export class CustomUrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
          shouldProcessUrl(url: UrlTree) {
          ....
          // your code
          }

           extract(url: UrlTree) {
             return url;
          }
          merge(url: UrlTree, whole: UrlTree) { return url; }
```

Then change your

```
 @NgModule({
    declarations: [ ...],
...
    providers: [...
       { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: CustomUrlHandlingStrategy }
    ]
});
```